# Calling Private Functions from combobox

Tags: vb.net

I need to build an application that could run code in private function, based on what user has selected using combobox.

For example combo box has three values, One, Two, Three

If user selects one, code written under Private Function One() runs and vise versa

Thanks

Furqan

Comment: -1 This is a dupe of **your own question** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059461/using-private-function, just even shorter and with `Three` added.

Comment: Please explain the problems you're experiencing with the solutions proposed as answers to your other question. This will make it easier for us to tailor our suggestions to your specific use, rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: Below is a sample which will show what I want   Public Class Form1
    Protected Sub One()
        MsgBox("One is called")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Two()
        MsgBox("Two is called")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Three()
        MsgBox("Three is called")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Call ComboBox1.Text
    End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152328/further-to-my-question-calling-private-functions-using-combobox). This works great!

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to assign  a function for when the combo box is selected.  Inside your function have a select statement like:  (Pesduo)

```
Function comboSelected

    Case "One"
        call Onefunction()
    Case "Two"
        call Twofunction()

End function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring these as private?

Form controls cannot access private functions.  You should declare them as protected.

Comment: This is not correct. Controls placed on a form can certainly access private members that are declared on the same form. You would only have to mark them as protected if you're trying to access members that are declared in a form class that is higher up the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Are we talking Windows forms or Web forms here?

Comment: My bad, I'm assuming WinForms because that seemed to be the consensus for his last question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to make it work - assuming Windows Forms.

First, define this class:

```
Public Class ComboAction

    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String, ByVal action As Action)
        _text = text
        _action = action
    End Sub

    Private _text As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _action As Action
    Public ReadOnly Property Action() As Action
        Get
            Return _action
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Text
    End Function

End Class
```

Now create a form like this:

```
Public Class ComboActionForm

    Private Sub ComboActionForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(New ComboAction("Show Foo", AddressOf Foo))
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(New ComboAction("Show Bar", AddressOf Bar))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Foo()
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Foo")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Bar()
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Bar")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        CType(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem, ComboAction).Action.Invoke()
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can add as many `ComboAction` classes to the `ComboBox` as you wish. Each can have any `Action` you define - private methods or otherwise. The sky is the limit. :-)