# Further to my question: Calling private functions using combobox

Tags: vb.net

Below is my code that I want to run.  I want to call the same function that user choses from the combo box.  Please advise how it can be managed.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub One()
    MsgBox("One is called")
End Sub
Private Sub Two()
    MsgBox("Two is called")
End Sub
Private Sub Three()
    MsgBox("Three is called")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim vrTextNow As String = ComboBox1.Text
    Call vrTextNow
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use reflection to achieve this. [Reflection is the process by which a computer program can observe and modify its own structure and behavior at runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29)

Add `Imports System.Reflection` before your class definition and use this code in you ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged method

```
Dim vrTextNow As String = ComboBox1.Text
        Dim method As MethodInfo
        method = Me.GetType().GetMethod(vrTextNow, BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        method.Invoke(Me, Nothing)
```